# Flutter: Validate TextFormField not working in my case

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, validation

I have 2 TextFormField, in first TextFormField, get data from bottomsheet and assign this data to controller, in second TextFormField, just a normal text field to enter a text. Code like this:

```
TextFormField(
                      onTap: () {
                        // This is bottomsheet
                        showBottomsheet(
                          context,
                          filterOptions:
                              context.read<EOfficeBloc>().registerMeetingOption,
                        );
                         context.read<EOfficeBloc>()
                              .applyFilterRegisterMeeting(
                                  filterOption: filterOption);
                      },
                      readOnly: true,
                      controller:
                          context.read<EOfficeBloc>().meetingRoomController,
                      validate: (value) {
                        if (meetingRoom?.isEmpty ?? false) {
                          return 'Validate';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
),
TextFormField(
                      validate: (value) {
                        if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                          return 'Validate';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onChange: (value) {
                        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                          int quantity = int.parse(value);
                          final filterOption = context
                              .read<EOfficeBloc>()
                              .registerMeetingOption
                              .copyWith(peopleNumber: quantity);
                          context
                              .read<EOfficeBloc>()
                              .applyFilterRegisterMeeting(
                                  filterOption: filterOption);
                        }
                      },
                      controller:
                          context.read<EOfficeBloc>().peopleNumberController,
)
```

In class bloc:

```
  TextEditingController? meetingRoomController;
  TextEditingController? peopleNumberController;

  void applyFilterRegisterMeeting({
    required RegisterInformationMeetingFilterOption filterOption,
  }) {
    _registerMeetingOption = filterOption.copyWith();
    if (filterOption.meetingRoomList.isNotEmpty) {
      meetingRoomController =
          TextEditingController(text: filterOption.meetingRoomList.first.name);
    }
    if (filterOption.peopleNumber != null) {
      peopleNumberController =
          TextEditingController(text: filterOption.peopleNumber.toString());
    }
}
```

The issue is: when i choose data in bottomsheet and apply, meetingRoomController had data with field 'name' but value in validate is empty so it not hide a text 'Validate'. And then when i click in second TextFormField and type a text, value in validate of first TextFormField only hide 'Validate'. I dont know reason why not hide 'Validate' when i choose a data in bottomsheet?
Im very bad in english, so help me pls. Thank u very much!

Comment: Do you mean to be using validator property? I'm not sure of the validate property for TextFormField. Looking at documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html#material.TextFormField.1

Comment: It mean, when i choose and apply data from bottomsheet in meetingRoomController, value in param validate in first TextFormField is empty, when i enter a text in second TextFormField, value in param validate in first TextFormField had data from bottomsheet, so why is empty?

Answer (score 1):

The current page does not update from actions on bottomSheet.

Make use of **StatefulBuilder** as:

```
   showModalBottomSheet<void>(
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context, StateSetter updateState) {
                  return MaterialButton(onPressed: () {
                    updateState(() {
                      // Update the textfiled value here

                      // Or use your preferred state management tool
                    });
                  });
                });
              },
            );
```

Also, ensure you make use of Form Widget with a form key to validate the declared validators on the TextFormField:

For more insight on TextField/TextFormField validation check the official cookbook: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: I was updated in bottomSheet like this:
```bottomSheet(
      context,
      isDismissible: false,
      childAbsolutely: (_) => SelectionBottomSheet<MeetingRoom>(
        title: LocaleKeys.meetingRoom_meetingRoom.tr(),
        onInitData: context.read<EOfficeBloc>().fetchMeetingRooms(),
        onApply: (meetingRoomList) {
          context
              .read<EOfficeBloc>()
              .applyFilterRegisterMeeting(filterOption: filterOptions);
        },
      ),
    );```
function applyFilterRegisterMeeting